# How to draw mixed-formatted text with .Net 2.0

Tags: text, .net-2.0, system.drawing

is there a way to draw mixed-formatted text in .Net 2.0? I'm looking for something similar to

```
System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString()
```

My problem with this method is that it allows only one format style for the whole text. But I need to draw text that has different format styles (e.g. a part of the text shall be underlined, another part bold and so on).

Thanks a lot!
Oliver

Comment: What you're looking for is functionality that was added to .NET 3.5 (perhaps .NET 3.0?) -- I know of no native way to do this in .NET 2.0 -- There might be some 3rd party add-on that addresses this problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pulling an answer right from the book [WPF in Action](http://www.manning.com/feldman2/) -- You seem to have 2 options:

> - *Create a custom control and define your own markup for specifying fonts*. Aside from this being a lot of work, you'd also have to rely on the the notoriously inaccurate methods for measuring the width of text (so that you could figure out where to put the next word).
> - *Use the RTF control*. This is extremely heavy, and you'd end up spending a lot of time making it look like text instead of an edit control, and you'd have to work with RTF to get the text the way you wanted.

So I guess the answer is the RTF control (aka. [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)) if you're stuck with .NET 2.0 -- WinForms. Well, unless you want to write your own control... :-)

The book also mentions taking various label and/or textbox controls and manually (or programatically) aligning them and setting to have different font values, etc. But I assume you want to avoid that, right?

**EDIT**

I'm leaving my above answer in-place. Here's my new answer to you:

Look into GDI+ -- Here is a link to a tutorial at C# Corner which should introduce you to GDI+: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041am/gdi_plus.aspx

And here is a link that should show you how to use GDI+ with a Bitmap/Image: http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/05/05/gdiplus.html

Good luck!

Also, you may want to pick up a book on this as GDI+ is a pretty heavy topic. I did most of my learning about GDI+ via the book [Pro .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Custom Controls in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594398) (It's a good book in my experience.) Although since you aren't exactly interested in designing custom controls for WinForms, you may want to look for a book geared more directly toward GDI+.

Comment: Hi,

my problem with the RichTextBox: I don't want to display the text in an application, but I want to draw it on a System.Drawing.Bitmap object and then save it as a PNG file.

I thought about using the RichTextBox as input element but I don't know how to draw the text on the Bitmap object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTML to markup your text try this:

```
Private Sub DrawHTMLString(sHTML As String, rct As RectangleF, dpiX As Single, dpiY As Single, g As Graphics)
    DrawHTMLString(sHTML, rct.X, rct.Y, rct.Width, rct.Height, dpiX, dpiY, g)
End Sub

Private Sub DrawHTMLString(sHTML As String, x As Single, y As Single, width As Single, height As Single, dpiX As Single, dpiY As Single, g As Graphics)
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear
    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

    g.DrawImage(DrawHTMLString(sHTML, width, height, dpiX, dpiY), x, y)
End Sub

Private Function DrawHTMLString(sHTML As String, width As Single, height As Single, dpiX As Single, dpiY As Single) As Bitmap
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = Nothing
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = Nothing

    Using wb As New WebBrowser()
        wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        wb.Navigate("about:blank")

        wb.Width = width : wb.Height = height

        doc = wb.Document.OpenNew(True)
        doc.Write(sHTML)

        bmp = New Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        bmp.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY)

        wb.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height))
    End Using

    Return bmp
End Function
```

(Sorry, it's in VB.NET)
Play with it as you will.